# Create a C# .net DriveService object using existing access token

Tags: google-drive-api

In my application, I already have the access token retrieved and now I want to use to access files using DriveService?  Is this possible to do with the sdk?  I am able to do this for the Google Spreadsheets service just fine, using OAUTH2PARAMETERS and GOAuth2RequestFactory (code below).  Can I do something similar to instantiate DriveService object in C# sdk for web apps?

```
OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters
            {
                TokenType = "Bearer",
                AccessToken = <access_token>,
            };

var requestFactory = new GOAuth2RequestFactory("svc", "appname", parameters);

SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("svc");
            service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;
```

Comment: are you using Googles .net client lib?

Comment: yes, I am using the Google .net client lib from nuget.

Comment: You didn't post any code so I will assume you are using filedatastore.   You can replace filedatastore by creating your own instance of iDatastore that uses your own refreshtoken.

Comment: I am doing the oauth dance to retrieve the access token from the refresh token etc.  using some other mechanism, not the client libs.  Once I have the token, how can I create the DriveService object is my question.

Comment: anyone knows the answer to this?